# Call stack has exceeded maximum of depth of 100 ,Lua

Tags: lua

```
function findWord(s,i)
   -- find first word in given text
   local j = i+1

   while not _isWhite(s:byte(j)) and j < #s do  -- getting error here
      j = j + 1
   end
   return s:sub(i,j), j
end  

function splitText(s,maxLen)
   -- split text into chunks of maxLen length

    rs ={}
   local function _g(s,i,c,rs) 
      -- recursively split text 

     local function _f(s,i,c)      
         -- recursively find words and add each word to a chunk     
         local w,i = findWord(s,i)                

         if i == #s then return c..w end

         if  #(c..w) <= maxLen  then
            c = c..w 
            s = s:sub(i+1,#s,true)
            return _f(s,1,c)

         else
            return c
         end
      end         

      rs[#rs+1] = _f(s,1,'')
      i = i+#rs[#rs]      

      if i < #s then 
         local s = s:sub(i,#s,true)
         return _g(s,1,'',rs)         
      else
         return rs          
      end
   end

   return _g(s,1,'',rs)
end
```

I have above function to split a string, It has been working earlier but this time it started giving error "call stack has exceeded maximum of depth of 100, verify a function is not calling itself by accident."
Any idea why I might be getting this error, this behaviour seems random since I am quite sure about rest of the script and same split function has been working fine as well.

**EDIT:**
Yes, isWhiteSpace was provided to me and has the following code, I am not supposed to change it since it worked earlier . Here is isWhite function:

```
function _isWhite(byte) 
  return byte == 32 or byte == 9 
end
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? Split words around whitespace? That would be better done using patterns and gmatch.

Comment: @dr01d3k4 : Yes, isWhiteSpace was provided to me and has the following code, I am not supposed to change it since it worked earlier . Here is isWhite function:                                function _isWhite(byte) 
    return byte == 32 or byte == 9
    end

Comment: I just wish to know the reason for this error

Comment: Can you provide the actual call for `splitText` it errors on (the string and maxlen parameters)?

Answer (score 1):

So both `_g` and `_f` call themselves, and `_g` calls `_f`. So clearly the recursion-stop conditions you have are too weak. In `_g` I see

```
  if i < #s then 
     local s = ...
     return _g(s,1,'',rs)         
  else
     return rs          
  end
```

which will stop when i >= #s. If this never happens, you will get infinite recursion. It is hard to say by looking at the code how i varies, but based on this line:

```
i = i+#rs[#rs]
```

it appears to by some value, but can't say if there is guarantee that stop condition will ever be reached. With `_f` it is worse: the stop recursion conditions are

```
if i == #s then return c..w end
```

and

```
#(c..w) > maxLen
```

Again very hard to say if this is strong enough: what if i is greater than #s, does the rest of the function work? Although `findWord()` returns i<#s for non empty s, not sure what will happen if s empty.

Best way to find out is to put some print statements that give you a trace of `_g` and `_f` and the parameters received, this will tell you clearly what stop conditions are being missed.